# Reformatted Windows 8 laptop not loading Installed Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, uefi

I have a new(er) HP Pavillion G6, and I completely wiped the hard drive to install ubuntu primarily, with a small Windows 7 partition. I created a partition for "/", the "/home" directory, a little for swap, and one for the windows section. Finished installing, restarted, it says "boot device not found, please install operating system. What steps should I take to install ubuntu and windows 7? Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/159545).

Comment: There are too many unknowns in your description. (For this reason, I would ***NOT*** recommend flagging this question as a duplicate just yet.) Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates; this should provide the information that's necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch, sounds like you need to check out the [UEFI Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) from Ubuntu. If it was a Windows 8 machine, it can be a pain. Stopped buying those Windows machines because of that annoyance. There are other options, but this is a forum to help with Ubuntu questions.